# Java BMI Calculator Issue - Imperial or Metric User Input, Error Handling, Correct Values Input, Conversion

Tags: java, error-handling, user-input

I am currently working on my first Java program for my final assignment as a beginner programmer, however, I am quite confused with some parts of it. I saw that there are a lot of BMI calculator source codes but most of them are very simple. 
  My assignment, however, requires input of Imperial or Metric values, conversion of the input from Metric to Imperial or vice versa, error handling, and validation of user input. I won't even try to use a GUI, so if someone can give me some directions for the simple form of the program, I would be very grateful.
Here is my code so far (I hope it's not a total mess):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BodyMassIndex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

       double weightKg, weightPounds, weightStones, heightCm, heightMeters, 
               heightFeet, heightInches, bMIMetric, bMIImperial;

       System.out.println("Please, enter your weight in kilograms: ");
       weightKg = input.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Please enter your height in centimeters: ");
       heightCm = input.nextDouble(); 

       String correctValues1;
       if (weightKg < 20 && weightKg > 400) {
           System.out.println("Please enter valid weight.");
           correctValues1 = "Please enter valid weight.";
       }
       if (heightCm < 20 && heightCm > 250) {
           System.out.println("Please enter valid height.");
           correctValues1 = "Plase enter valid height.";
       }

       System.out.println("Please, enter your weight in pounds: ");
       weightPounds = input.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches: ");
       heightInches = input.nextDouble();

       String correctValues2;
       if (weightPounds < 44 && weightPounds > 882) {
       System.out.println("Please enter valid weight.");
       correctValues2 = "Please enter valid weight.";
       }
       if (heightInches < 7 && heightInches > 98) {
       System.out.println("Please enter valid height.");
       correctValues2 = "Please enter valid height.";
       }

       heightMeters = heightCm/100;
       weightPounds = weightKg*0.453592;
       weightStones = weightKg*6.35029318;
       heightFeet = heightCm*0.0328084;
       heightInches = heightCm*0.393701;

       bMIMetric = (weightKg/(heightMeters*heightMeters));

       bMIImperial = (weightPounds/(heightInches*heightInches))*703;

    System.out.printf("Height in meters is %.2f\n", heightMeters);
    System.out.printf("Weight in pounds is %.2f\n", weightPounds);
    System.out.printf("Weight in stones is %.2f\n", weightStones);
    System.out.printf("Height in feet is %.2f\n", heightFeet);
    System.out.printf("Height in inches is %.2f\n", heightInches);

    String Result1;
            if (bMIMetric < 18.5) {
            System.out.println("less than 18.5");
            Result1 = "Underweight";
            } else if ((bMIMetric) >= 18.5 && (bMIMetric) <= 24.9) {
            System.out.println("between 18.5 and 24.9");
            Result1 = "Normal";
            } else if (bMIMetric >= 25 && bMIMetric <= 29.9) {
            System.out.println("between 25 and 29.9");
            Result1 = "Overweight";
            } else {
            System.out.println("greater than 30");
            Result1 = "Obese";
            }

    String Result2;
            if (bMIImperial < 18.5) {
            System.out.println("less than 18.5");
            Result2 = "Underweight";
            } else if ((bMIImperial) >= 18.5 && (bMIImperial) <= 24.9) {
            System.out.println("between 18.5 and 24.9");
            Result2 = "Normal";
            } else if (bMIImperial >= 25 && bMIImperial <= 29.9) {
            System.out.println("between 25 and 29.9");
            Result2 = "Overweight";
            } else {
            System.out.println("greater than 30");
            Result2 = "Obese";
            }

    System.out.println("Your Body Mass Index is:" + bMIMetric + "(" + Result1 +")");
    System.out.println("Your Body Mass Index is:" + bMIImperial +"(" + Result2 +")");

        }
    }
```

Comment: If your user has already entered their mass in kg and height in cm, is there really a need to ask for those again in lbs and inches?

Comment: why to ask the user to enter the weight and height in both Imperial and Metric, provide an option first asking what unit user wants to enter. Secondly, if incorrect values are called, instead of asking user to input again, why not call the main method again.

Comment: Maybe fits better in codereview. But one suggestion, ask user if they want to input metric or imperial. Then the output should be the same for imp/metric since it is a quota

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make it complex, which is actually not easy task. 
As a consequence youre making redundand and nonlogical steps.

**input**
Youre asking for double input in different metric. For example weight in kilograms and in pounds. You need to ask user which metric is he using and start from there.

**error checking** 
I'd suggest to use try/catch block and look for non numerical values

```
try {
    // get your input
} catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
    // try again
}
```

hope this helps a bit

Comment: HI dram, thanks for your reply. I'll try to integrate it into my code.

Answer (score -1):

The intention of what you have below is great--checking to make sure that the entered parameters are correct. However, it only error checks once and does not provide the user with what the correct values should be. (Also it should be an or, not and, as that condition right now can never be true.)

```
   String correctValues2;
       if (weightPounds < 44 && weightPounds > 882) {
       System.out.println("Please enter valid weight.");
       correctValues2 = "Please enter valid weight.";
       }
```

I would suggest something more along the lines of:

```
     while (weightPounds < 44 || weightPounds > 882) {
           System.out.println("Please enter valid weight.(44 lb - 882 lb)");
           weightPounds = input.nextDouble();
           }
```

This way you are able to avoid the need for a 'correct value' string and ensure that the value is correct when you exit the while loop.

Also, if the program is supposed to specify whether or not the user want's their BMI in metric or imperial, ask that FIRST.

By the way, this post probably belongs in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for future reference

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I also want to ask the user to input metric or imperial in the beginning. I tried it with a switch statement, however, I didn't know how to connect it to the code afterwards. As in, if the user chooses Imperial, the program to take him to the Imperial input code block and then finish with the BMI calculation and a reset of the program. My switch statement looked like this (posted in a separate comment):

Comment: My statement looked like this:
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("1\t Metric");
   System.out.println("2\t Imperial");
   System.out.println("3\t Quit");

        System.out.println("Please enter your choice:");
        int choice=in.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Metric"); 
    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Imperial");
                    break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Quit"); 
                    break;
            default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");

Comment: Also thank you for referring me to Code Review, I'll try to get some help there as well.

Comment: Maybe an enumerator would work well here to set the "State" of your calculator. An enumerator is just a variable that internally is an integer, but lets you call each number much easier to remember names, such as IMPERIAL and METRIC. Read up on it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html . You can then use the enumerator to, at different places in your program, check if state==METRIC or state==IMPERIAL (you can even use it in switch/case statements!)